# Compare two integer arrays and check if they have equal values

Tags: c++, arrays, compare, time-complexity, binary-search

I want to know what is the best way to compare two **unsorted** arrays and check them if they have equal values using C++?
I found a solution in O(nlogn) but is there a O(n) solution for this? how, if yes?

Please let me tell you that this is not an university question, I like to know for ACM problem solving.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the arrays of equal length? Does ordering of elements within the arrays matter? For instance are [9, 2, 5] and [5, 2, 9] equal?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `O(n lg n)` is the best you can do.

Comment: @o11c yeah, unless he cam make any other assumptions about the data, I believe you are right.

Comment: No, the arrays aren't equal lengths.

Comment: If they are not of equal length, it's easy, right? Because then they aren't equal. Or how do you define equality!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your values are and how much memory your are willing to spend on this. In an O(n) solution for arrays that contain *unique* integers x in the range 0 <= x < c, you could use an auxiliary array `char count[c]` and do something like this:

```
int array1[N];
int array2[N];

//get the values into array1 and 2 from somehwere

char count[c]{0};
for(size_t i=0; i<N; i++) {
    count[array1[i]]++;
    count[array2[i]]++;
}
```

Now, the two arrays will be equal if and only if all the elements of `count` are either 0 or 2. This can be checked in O(n) by running the same loop again, only this time, `count[array1[i]]` (and the same for `array2`) are checked to be equal to 2. The same technique can be adapted for a few other scenarios: For example, if the values are non-unique, you have to count in two separate arrays and then check the two counts for equality. However, if the number of possible values is too large, you have to resort to storing your information ('x is contained in array') in a different structure like a tree where the operations are in O(n log n), so you are back to where you started.

Comment: Thank you for your response but the values aren't bounded in a range for example we may have a array in size of 20 with a value of 23967!

Comment: Well, the other issue is that (especially for small n like 20), you don't actually care so much about O(...), but about the absolute time it needs. The prefactors, i.e. a and b in a\*n and b\*n\*log(n), can significantly vary depending on the approach, so if you are generally dealing with smallish arrays, better look for the best approach for the *typical* size in terms of absolute time, than for the one with the best asymptotic behavior.

Comment: I may be missing something but this doesn't seem valid to me even if there was a range of values. For instance if array1 = [1, 1, 2, 2] and array2 = [3, 3, 4, 4] wouldn't count be [0, 2, 2, 2, 2]? According to my reading of your solution, that would mark those two arrays as equal. EDIT: I missed the word unique...

Comment: Yes, they have to be unique for the above to work. But as mentioned in the answer, you could apply the same approach (with two different counting arrays) to arrays with non-unique values.